# Using RDP with multiple remote monitors

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have a local windows 7 machine with 1 monitor, and a remote window 7 machine with 2 monitors.

I want to RDP to the remote machine, but I want to be able to duplicate my remote machines dual screen set up, where I can switch between the 2 remote monitors from my local computer (this functionality is available in Teamviewer and GOTOMYPC). When I log on, currently I get a single window showing which re-sizes the contents of *both* my remote screens to a single screen.

So I would like a single window on local side with a switch/toggle/button to switch between looking at my remote screens 1 or 2.

Is this possible?

Comment: I mean there are a few questions about using multiple LOCAL monitors, mine is about multiple REMOTE monitors. I was worried that a casual reader might not notice that.

Comment: TeamViewer/VNC and Terminal Services are fundamentally different in how they capture what is sent over the net. TS *does not mirror* remote displays.

Comment: Does your local machine only have 1 monitor? I'm a little lost here... Normally when I connect to some where with multiple monitors, it only shows me 1 screen (if my client only has 1 monitor)... Do you use any params, such as /multimon or /span etc?

Comment: yes only 1 monitor on local machine. But I want to switch what that one screen sees to be either my remote screen 1 or my remote screen 2. Currently RDP creates a single combined view.  The /multimon or /span flags appear to do nothing

Comment: VNC might be an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602985/vnc-viewer-with-multiple-monitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RDP does not supports this...

It will resize/re-organise the screen to 1 monitor as you describe.

However, you need to note the remote machine (the one you are connecting too) needs to be Windows 7 Ultimate or Windows 7 Enterprise edition as they are the only ones to support the use of multiple monitors for RDP

Comment: Messing up the icons etc is a pain, BUT my real issue is that on the remote machine I use the two screens for specifically different things. And when I remote in I want to work in the same way. I don't suppose there is any path I could run on my remote windows 7 pro that would give me Enterprise functionality - just for RDP?

Comment: I seriously do suggest just buying a second monitor for home...

Answer (score 4):

Windows RDP does not support this. When you connect to RDP, it just starts a new session with new monitor settings. It doesn't look at the hardware from the remote server.

Also with sound and such. It transfers the sound to the local computer and not the remote computer.

Comment: Audio redirection is optional, but in essence this is the very reason this will not ever work with RDP/Terminal Services.

Answer (score 1):

I've used TeamViewer which can display each remote monitor within a window on your local monitor. To look at a monitor, I just move the associated window to the foreground.